# Pets, On-hit, On-ability and other effects

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to know how On-hit and On-ability works with **pets**, more specifically on Malzahar's Voidlings. I'm testing a hybrid build, and I know that Voidlings will get AD and ArmorPen from Malzahar, but I don't know some fundamental questions, like:

1. If I get a item with life steal like **Vampiric Scepter**, when the Voidling atacks, who will recover HP, Malzahar, the Voidling, both, or neither?
2. Will the on-hit passive from **The Black Cleaver**, **Phage**, **Statikk Shiv**, and other similar items be applied to Voidling's hits?
3. Would critical strike chance apply to Voidlings too?

Comment: my immediated answer is no, nothing affects the voidling...more testing is required

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pets do not inherit item effects (either passive or active). The only item effects that *would* affect pets are such effects like [Banner of Command](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Banner_of_Command), [Runic Bulwark](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runic_Bulwark) (and its component item, [Aegis of the Legion](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aegis_of_the_Legion)), and the [Captain](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Captain) boot enchant.

Specifically, Malzahar's pets scale strictly off of his stats and are not affected by anything other than these items, meaning that also will not proc Red Buff. Malzahar's pets also do not inherit life steal.

P.S. If you have questions about other items, look for the keyword "minion". Unless specified in such a way, most items will not affect pets.

Comment: An interesting fact is that for example Zyra's plants and Heimerdinger's turrets are not pets. So, for example, Rylai's Crystal Scepter triggers its effects on plants and turrets.

Answer (score 2):

Although voidlings will NOT proc on-hit effects, they WILL do physical damage with their attacks. Now, the description of the Black Cleaver says:
"Dealing physical damage to an enemy champion reduces their armor by 6.25% for 4 seconds"
In theory, voidlings should reduce the armor of enemy champions because their damage is listed as Malzahar's damage. Try it, and find out for yourself ;)