# Does the Butcher item passive apply to pet and trap damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are a number of champions who can summon pets in League of Legends. When I say pets I mean Malzahar's voidlings, Elise's spiders, Yorick's ghouls, Shaco's clone, etc.

Do these creatures also do increased damage if the champion owns an item with the butcher passive?

Does a champion's traps also do increased damage when they own a butcher passive? Examples would be Shaco's Jack in the Box, Nidalee's bushwhack (assuming it can trigger on monsters), etc.

Comment: Related (or duplicated?) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96160/pets-on-hit-on-ability-and-other-effects

Comment: bushwhack does trigger on minions / monsters.

Comment: Traps will get the added damage. I would assume pets would as well but not sure so I'm not making this an answer.

Comment: Gonna do a test on this later, will let you know when it's done

Comment: Just kidding, working on this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with Nidalee for traps, then Malzahar for the pet. My runes pages and Masteries were both empty to make sure those had no effect on this test.

Both of these tests were done on the big blue golem at lvl 1 (0MR, 9Armor)

**Nid's Trap damage (no machete)** - 80(20 per tick) so normal damage since jungle creeps have no MR at the beginning.

**Malz pet damage (no machete)** - 20 each attack

**Trap damage (with machete)** - 88(22 per tick) so yes, there is a 10% increase there.

**Pet damage (with machete)** - 22 each attack, 10% increase here too.

Any other champ tests you want me to do, just leave a comment.